# Insert two arrays of data in the same time in a database

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have two arrays $fuel and $hours, with same number of data and i want to insert them in the same time in a database.

here is what i have:

```
$fuellength = count($fuel);
$f = 0;             

for($f=0;$f<$fuellength;$f++){ 
if ($fuel[$f] > 0){
    if (
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO grafiku (vehicle_plate, fuel_level, date_hour) VALUES (".$userid.", ".$hours[$f].",     '".$fuel[$f]."')");
        ) 
        echo "data has been inserted"; 
     else 
        echo "data has not been inserted";
 } //end if 
}//end for
```

It shows me nothing!  Is it correct to use 'for' loop for arrays? Or should i use only 'foreach'? If so, how can i loop throw both arrays in the same time??

Thanks in advance!
Best regards

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Comment: This calls for basic debugging. What value is `$fuellength`? Does your query actually succeed? (http://php.net/mysql_error)

Comment: What does these variables contains??

$userid,$hours[$f],$fuel[$f
Use var_dump() to find the values of varaibles you used

Comment: They all contain integer numbers

Comment: The lengths of the arrays (fuel and hour) are equal?

Comment: yes! they are equal since they have matching values. I mean, one hour has one fuel level value

Comment: @Pekka웃 the query does succeed with (fixed) given numbers. $fuel_length is a integer (number)

Comment: Can you show us your table structure? I want to see the fields' types.

Comment: grafiku.id  int not Null PK,
grafiku.vehicle_plate int not Null,
grafiku.fuel_level float not Null,
grafiku.date_hour datetime

Answer (score 0):

If your code is exactly like this you won't see anything because you have a fatal php error.
You have an `ELSE` statement whithout a starting `IF` statement.
Remove the comments from your `IF` statement and it should be working again.

Comment: the current IF doesnt match the ELSE statement, because the IF statement is closed just after the ELSE statement

Answer (score 0):

```
$fuellength = count($fuel);
$f = 0;             

for($f=0;$f<$fuellength;$f++){ 
if ($fuel[$f] > 0){
    $qryStr = "INSERT INTO grafiku (vehicle_plate, fuel_level, date_hour) VALUES (".$userid.", ".$hours[$f].",     '".$fuel[$f]."')";
    echo $qryStr."/br"; 
 } 
}
```

Check whether you are getting the query and the values.

Comment: No query, nor values showed. not even an error message shown.. that's not so good :/

Comment: That means either its not getting into the for loop or if statement.Thats why its not showing anything.I guess you $fuel didnt contain anything.Try print_r($fuel) or var_dump($fuel) to retrive the contents.

Comment: Means you are getting nothing in your variables.Can you show where you are getting values for $fuel array

Comment: '$j = 0;
for($j=0;$j<$arrlength;$j++){                      for($k=0;$k<$alength; $k++){      
$time=$hours[$j];                                                     if($time==$a[$k]){                                                              $fuel[$j]=$b[$k];                     }
else                                                   {$fuel[$j]=$temp;                                                       $value = $fuel[$j];                                                         }                                        $temp =$fuel[$j];} }'

Comment: the case is a bit complicated because i take some incomplete data(hours&fuel)from the database and fill in 2 arrays ($a & $b),i take an array of all hours of day($hours); an empty array ($fuel),i compare the 2 arrays of hours and for the hours missing in the $b array, i give to $fuel the last value of the last matching hour.  hope you understand it, i don't know if i was clear enough..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have established a connection with your MySQL Server:

```
$cn = mysql_connect("hostname", "username", "password");
```

Assuming that you have selected your database:

```
mysql_select_db("databasename", $cn);
```

Your logic is correct. But your SQL insert order is not matching your fields. You are trying to insert `$fuel[$f]` data into `date_hour` field.

```
$f = 0;
$added = 0; 
$noAdded = 0;             

while($f < count($fuel))
{ 
    if ($fuel[$f] > 0) 
    { 
        if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO grafiku 
                   (vehicle_plate,   fuel_level,    date_hour) 
            VALUES (".$userid.",   ".$fuel[$f].", '".$hours[$f]."')"
        ))
            $added++; 
        else 
            $noAdded++;
    }

    $f++;
}

//Then you can display additional information after inserting is done. 

echo $added . " data has been added to table.";
echo "<br />";
echo $noAdded . " data could not be added to table.";
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in ../charts/fuel_db_test.php on line 129. it's the '$added++' line

Comment: Corrected. there was a missing `)` before `$added++;` line.

Comment: vehicle_plate has only numbers of 3 digits (exp: 345, 400, 564 ..etc) which are also the user_ids of that vehicle. In my case a vehicle is considered a user of the system. It is not about the vehicle plate we usually see..(like 'W 238 WK' plate in England)

Comment: After you sent your your table structure I deleted that idea and changed the code.

Comment: i used your code but it doesn't do the insert :/ It shows no error, but still won't do the job..

Comment: as @Deep said "Try `print_r($fuel)` or `var_dump($fuel)` to retrive the contents" and do this for the rest of all arrays you have. `echo` your SQL statement first instead of firing. Also take a look at your apache error log.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your code,
    Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE in < file name > on line 12

```
<?php

   $fuellength = count($fuel);
   $f = 0;             

  for($f=0;$f<$fuellength;$f++){ 
  if ($fuel[$f] > 0){
  if (mysql_query("INSERT INTO grafiku (vehicle_plate, fuel_level, date_hour) VALUES     (".$userid.", ".$hours[$f].",     '".$fuel[$f]."')")) 
    echo "data has been inserted"; 
     else 
    echo "data has not been inserted";
 } //end if 
 }//end for
?>
```